# How do I add a Wordpress newsletter on a Dot Net Nuke site?

Tags: web, dotnetnuke

I am interesting in adding a newsletter to my site.
The newsletter should be based off my wordpress site.
Any ideas as to how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just `IFrame` the newsletter onto an HTML module or there are some [IFrame Modules](http://dnniframe.codeplex.com/) available that would give you a little more control of the look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a section built into dnn for that navigate to admin>newsletters.... its right there and set up for you already! IF you have a problem, you can also use the feedback form module and set it to send to all users